# CSS table td width and right align not working

Tags: css, firefox, html-table, internet-explorer-7

This is my table in FireFox. Note that the center column, with the user name, is wide and the edit link is right aligned.

[image]

This is IE7 and IE8:

[image]

Here’s is the html:

```
    <fieldset >
    <legend>Account Information</legend>
    <table class="display-table">
        <tr>
            <td class="display-label">
                <label for="UserName">Username</label>
            </td>
            <td class="display-field-middle">
                user7
            </td>
            <td class="display-field-right">
                <a class="" href="/test1/Account/ChangeUserName">edit</a>


            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="display-label">
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
            </td>
            <td class="display-field-middle">
                *********
            </td>
            <td class="display-field-right">
                <a class="" href="/test1/Account/ChangePassword">edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
```

This is the FireBug display of the inherited styles:

[image]

Here is the style sheet:

```
.display-table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width: 400px;
}

.display-label
{   
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 120px;
}

.display-field-middle
{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #dfeffc;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}


.display-field-right
{
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #dfeffc;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Why isn’t the middle column expanding and why aren’t the edit links right aligned?
I’ve tried everything!

Comment: Works here in FF/IE8/IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/C4Qbx/ - so I don't think your question yet has all the information required to solve it.

Comment: Do you have any global rules in your CSS for * or td? For example: * { text-align:left; } -or- td { text-align:left; }

Comment: I forgot about Fiddle. Thank you. I updated my question to show the inherited styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was testing incorrectly and the page was working all along. :(